# add custom ffmpeg avfilter in mlt

Tags: opengl, ffmpeg, libav, video-editing, mlt

I created one custom filter under av filter and added it into ffmpeg.
I build the ffmpeg and in ffmpeg its working fine and visible in ffmpeg filter list.

Now I tried to build mlt with this custom ffmpeg. mlt build successfully.
I checked in mlt filters but it is not available.

On investigating I found in mlt there is no avfilter available which can take 2 videos as input.
As my filter also takes 2 videos as input and apply some filter and output one video that's why it's not available.

Now I want to know

1. Why mlt is not supporting multiple input av filters ?
2. Where in code mlt restricted it.
3. What is the best way to add this filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why mlt is not supporting multiple input av filters ?

MLT Filter objects only support input from one source. So using an AV filter with multiple inputs can not work. This is fundamental to the design of MLT.

> Where in code mlt restricted it.

https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/src/modules/avformat/factory.c#L448

> What is the best way to add this filter ?

MLT transitions can mix two frames from two different producers. It would be possible to design a new MLT transition similar to MLT filter that provides access to AV filters with two inputs.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I just had one more query.
I have seen fragment shader implementation in couple of transition effect (luma_mix) in movit library.
will it be feasible to add new transition effect supporting gl transition ?